# Sort an array of lines so the points in vertices are connected

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I have an array of lines. Each line connects with exactly one other line, meaning that they share the same point in the vertex. Example of an array:

```
((31,10),(48,50))
((20,33),(10,20))
((48,50),(60,81))
((10,20),(31,10))
```

The problem here is that the array is shuffled. I want to sort it so that 2nd point of the 1st line is the same as the 1st point of the 2nd line. The sorted array should look like this:

```
((20,33),(10,20))
((10,20),(31,10))
((31,10),(48,50))
((48,50),(60,81))
```

My idea was as it follows - Check every line with every line. When you find a line that shares the same point as another line, place it in a new array before or after the 1st line, depending if they share a point in the beginning or the end.

```
def sortLines():
    sortedLines = []
    for line1 in lines:
        if line1 not in sortedLines:
            sortedLines.append(line1)
        for line2 in lines:
            if line2 not in sortedLines:
                if line1.p1.equals(line2.p2): #If the beginning of line1 is connected to the end of line2
                    sortedLines.insert(sortedLines.index(line1), line2)
                if line1.p2.equals(line2.p1): #If the end of line1 is connected to the beginning of line2
                    sortedLines.insert(sortedLines.index(line1)+1, line2)
    return sortedLines
```

However, this only works partially - the ends are connected but the lines are still not sorted as they should be.

```
((10,20),(31,10))
((31,10),(48,50))
((48,50),(60,81))
((20,33),(10,20))
```

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the input data has all the segments connected to form a single segment?

Comment: @Tarik Yes, I have a method that checks that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to map the start and end coordinates of the lines.  The starting point is the key which is not also a value in the dictionary.

```
lines = [((31,10),(48,50)),
         ((20,33),(10,20)),
         ((48,50),(60,81)),
         ((10,20),(31,10))]

d = dict(lines)

sorted_lines = []
start = next(iter(d.keys() - d.values()))
while start in d:
    end = d[start]
    sorted_lines.append((start, end))
    start = end

print(sorted_lines)
```

gives (after some newlines inserted for readability):

```
[((20, 33), (10, 20)),
 ((10, 20), (31, 10)),
 ((31, 10), (48, 50)),
 ((48, 50), (60, 81))]
```

In the line:

```
start = next(iter(d.keys() - d.values()))
```

The keys and values behave like sets, so the differencing is used to extract what should be a 1-element set containing the key that is not also a value.  The `next(iter(...))` is used to extract that single member from the set.

---

If you want to support the possibility that the lines might form a polygon, then replace:

```
start = next(iter(d.keys() - d.values()))
```

with:

```
try:
    start = next(iter(d.keys() - d.values()))
except StopIteration:
    sorted_lines.append(lines[0])
    del d[lines[0][0]]    
    start = lines[0][1]
```

In that case, it will manually add the first line to the output and remove it from the dictionary, before carrying on with the rest of the algorithm starting from the next line.  Example with input:

```
lines = [((31,10),(48,50)),
         ((20,33),(10,20)),
         ((60,81),(20,33)),
         ((48,50),(60,81)),
         ((10,20),(31,10))]
```

gives:

```
[((31, 10), (48, 50)),
 ((48, 50), (60, 81)),
 ((60, 81), (20, 33)),
 ((20, 33), (10, 20)),
 ((10, 20), (31, 10))]
```

Comment: If the lines form a polygon, `next(iter(...))` will raise an exception.

Comment: @jferard I thought the question rather implied that there **is** an ordering, which would not be the case if the lines form a polygon.  If the OP would like to comment on this and state that it is required, then I can adapt the answer accordingly.

Comment: @jferard I've added an addendum as to how the code could be modified to cope with that case if required.

Comment: Hi is there anyone who can help me this solution in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can see your `lines` list as a graph. Each point is a vertex, each segment (couple of points) is an edge. You know that the graph is connected (segments are connected). @alaiwi idea is:

1. to represent the graph as an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list), with the specific property that each vertex has at most one neightbor, then
2. to search first the vertex that is not a neighbor and to follow the adjacency list until it ends.

Here's another idea: the graph is very specific because almost each vertex has a left neighbor and a right neighbor. Only the leftmost vertex has no left neighbor, and the rightmost vertex has no right neighbor. To get the ordered segments, you just need to start with *any* vertex and add left vertices to the left and right vertices to the right. (This is similar to the in order traversal of a binary tree.)

There is an optional check: if we loop over the vertices, then we have a polygon.

```
def order_segments(lines):
    def in_order(start):
        L = [start]
        e = left.get(start) # None if there is no left vertex
        while e != None:
            L.insert(0, e)
            e = left.get(e)

            if e == start: # optional: check for a polygon
                L.insert(0, e) # complete the polygon
                return L
                
        e = right.get(start) # None if there is no right vertex
        while e != None:
            L.append(e)
            e = right.get(e) # None if there is no right vertex

        return L

    # build the tree
    left = {}
    right = {}
    for e1, e2 in lines:
        right[e1] = e2
        left[e2] = e1

    start = lines[-1][0] # any vertex would be ok
    L = in_order(start) # the ordered vertices
    return list(zip(L, L[1:])) # build the segments

lines = [((31,10),(48,50)),
         ((20,33),(10,20)),
         ((48,50),(60,81)),
         ((10,20),(31,10))]

print(order_segments(lines))
# [((20, 33), (10, 20)), ((10, 20), (31, 10)), ((31, 10), (48, 50)), ((48, 50), (60, 81))]

print(order_segments([((60, 81), (20, 33))] + lines)) # a polygon
# [((10, 20), (31, 10)), ((31, 10), (48, 50)), ((48, 50), (60, 81)), ((60, 81), (20, 33)), ((20, 33), (10, 20))]
```